# Call Django API running on a server from Angular running locally

Tags: angularjs, django, api

I am learning with Django and Angular.

I have setup a Django API back-end on on `http://serverip:8666/athletics/`

I have created a small Angular application that I am running from my local machine.

The following code in my Angular app:

```
$scope.list_athletes = function(){

    console.log('hey');

    $http
        .get('http://serverip:8666/athletics/')
        .success(function (result) {

            console.log('success');

        })

}
```

generates the error:

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://serverip:8666/athletics/. No
>   'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource. Origin 'http://127.0.0.1:65356' is therefore not allowed
>   access.

What causes this error? How can I resolve it so that I can access the Django API from my local Angular app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem you're having is related to not having [CORS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing) enabled.

As a security policy, JavaScript can't make requests across domains while running in your browser. This is meant to prevent untrusted code from executing without the user's knowledge. The workaround is to enable CORS by white listing domains.

You need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin response header in your responses like so:

```
def my_view(request):
    data = json.dumps({'foo':'bar'})
    response = HttpResponse(data)
    response['Access-Control-Allow-Origin'] = 'http://127.0.0.1:65356'
    return response
```

This will enable CORS for your angular app. You can even add [django-cors-headers](https://github.com/ottoyiu/django-cors-headers) to your project to have this functionality implemented for you. This can be added to any Django response object, such as [`django.http.repsonse.HttpResponse`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/response.py#L31). Because you appear to be using a DRF Response object, you may need to use something like

```
return Response(serializer.data, headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http://127.0.0.1:65356'})
```

to set your response headers.

You should also check out [this site](http://enable-cors.org/) for more information on how to enable CORS in your webapp.

Comment: Where should I add that line? Is it in the Django app? I only have one response in my simple Angular app. It is "return Response(serializer.data)"

Comment: Looks like django-rest-framework's Response object, so you could try 'return Response(serializer.data, headers={'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': 'http: //127.0.0.1:65356/'})

Comment: That worked, thanks! (I removed the space after http: and the / after the port number.)

Answer (score 0):

Have you done the settings part in settings.py

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'corsheaders',
)
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
)
CORS_ORIGIN_WHITELIST = (
  'http://127.0.0.1:65356'
)
```

And also include CORS_ALLOW_CREDENTIALS, CORS_ALLOW_HEADERS settings

Comment: The previous answer worked. I have not done the settings you suggest. Are those settings an alternative solution?

Comment: yes. This is an important config you got to add in the settings to allow front end or other domains to access your Backend.

Comment: I couldn't get that to work. With your proposed method I got an error message that "XMLHttpRequest cannot load ... No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin ... is therefore not allowed access.".